# Extract characters after character '_' in string

Tags: sql, string

I have the following string in sql server where the length is variable

```
Declare @string Varchar(max) = 'abjrc_chdc_hyku_abv_ytr_DCD_HTR_TBF'
```

How could I select the characters after the 4th '_' in this string? (expected result: ytr_DCD_HTR_TBF)

Also how to select only the 4th part of the string (result: abv)

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: which db you are using?

Comment: I'm using sql server

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly how many characters are in the string at any time, then you can use [SUBSTRING](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_substring.asp), so you can call the first string like this

```
Declare @string Varchar(max) = 'abjrc_chdc_hyku_abv_ytr_DCD_HTR_TBF';
Declare @last4 Varchar(max) = SELECT SUBSTRING(@string, 21, 35);
Declare @before4 Varchar(max) = SELECT SUBSTRING(@string, 17, 19);
```

If y ou really need to split the string for each '_' then you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x) as well
hope i helped.

Comment: The substring work if the @string does not change, however I'm looking a Dynamic query to select the required characters. The length between the '_' is varaible

Comment: Look up at the link i left in the comment, i think it migth help you

Answer (score 0):

If you will do it for multiple line creating function would be better. I have prepared sample for your two question :

```
Declare @string Varchar(max) = 'abjrc_chdc_hyku_abv_ytr_DCD_HTR_TBF'
Declare @NewString Varchar(max) = @string
Declare @Find4thPart Varchar(max) =''

DECLARE @Sep    VARCHAR(10)='_'
DECLARE @Pos    INT=4

WHILE @Pos>0
BEGIN
SET @NewString = SUBSTRING(@NewString, CHARINDEX(@Sep,@NewString)+1,100)

IF @Pos=2
SET @Find4thPart = SUBSTRING(@NewString,1, CHARINDEX(@Sep,@NewString)-1)

SET @Pos=@Pos-1
--SELECT @NewString 
END

seLECT @NewString ,@Find4thPart
```